# Adding People or Look-up type Column to SharePoint 2010 List Breaks MS Access Linked Table

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2007

So I have a custom list in SharePoint 2010 with 10 or so columns.  I then link the list within MS Access 2007.  Works just fine until I try adding a look-up or people-type column to the list, then the next time I refresh the MS Access table link I get the following message:

Error:  "The Microsoft datbase engine cannot find the object 'TMP%.MAU@'.  Make sure the object exists..."  blah, blah, blah

Then of course, the data is inaccessible through MS Access after that point.  If I then go back to SharePoint and delete the new column, it starts working again in MS Access.

I can add any other kind of columns, and it works fine.

What gives?  Is there s limit to the number of people columns you can have in an MS Access linked SharePoint List?

========

## New Information

So I deleted all of the data from the sharepoint list, and the error went away, no matter how many people columns I added.  But as soon as you add a single record back in, the error returns...  :(

Comment: Followed those steps, and the link re-creation completes normally, but when you try to access the table you get the following error message:  The Microsoft Database Engine could not find the object [linked list name].  Make sure..."  blah blah

Comment: When importing, everything works fine and I can't see anything that helps me troubleshoot the issue any better.  I am using Acess 2007, an accdb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The error stems from a "hidden" threshold limit set within SharePoint Central Administration that limits the number of lookup columns returned within a given query.  This means linked MS Access lists to SharePoint would be limited as well, hence the error.  The problem is MS Access 2007 doesn't give you a nice error message to explain this to you, whereas SharePoint 2010 does.

The fix is simple--just bump up the threshold and you're good to go.  Here is how: [enter link description here](http://www.mainsoft.com/content/lookup-limit-error-sharepoint-2010-0x8007009)

Comment: Hi @David-W-Fenton. Yes, sorry, I said SharePoint 2010 error message when what I really meant was A2010 error message.  It was in fact the A2010 error message that led me to the solution. The error message basically told you that you had exceeded the lookup threshold. That was the first I had even heard a threshold setting existed. A quick bing of "sharepoint lookup threshold" revealed the setting in Central Administration.

Answer (score 1):

This does work in Access 2010.

I suspect you need thus Access 2010 use such a multi-value type of column. While 2007 does support SharePoint, I thinking this is a new type of column in SharePoint.

When you say you are adding a people type, then I assume you are choosing "Person or Group" as a SharePoint type. You are then setting this column as multiple choice.

This does work just fine for me in Access 2010. Even in table edit view from the Access side I get the multi-choice pick list, so I am thinking this is an Access 2007 limitation. Note that I do NOT need delete + re-link to see the changes after I add the new column. I did however right click on the table in Access, then choose more options, and then then refresh list. I get this view inside of access when I use that column:

[image]

I also find I can add new columns from inside of Access to this linked table if you use the table tab on the ribbon. The people picker is not a legal type from the choices in Access, but adding from SharePoint does work for me.

The only thing I might be doing different from you is the table was originally created and uploaded from Access.

Comment: I appreciate your testing effort with Access 2010, Albert.  However, I am trying to get this working for Access 2007.  Also, I have determined that this is not limit to people-picker type columns--it happens with any lookup-type column (which the people type column is, I guess).